# How to vertical center a div with position fixed and width in px?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to center a div with position fixed. And its width is specified as 300px and not in percentage.

```
<div class="mainCont">
  <div class="childCont">
</div>
```

`childCont` is div with fixed pos and width 300px. I want to make it as center.

Comment: it's more likely to get a response if there's a fiddle in the question, it's easier for everyone to see what you have tried and make changes to it and post it as a part of their answer. Nevertheless, have you tried using `margin:auto`?

Comment: You want horizontally of vertically center?

Comment: actually i'm trying to display popup so I need both  horizontally & vertically center

Comment: Is the height is also fixed?

Comment: no height is auto...

Comment: use `transform: translate(50%, 50%); right: 50%; bottom: 50%`.

Answer (score 1):

Use following css:

```
.childCont {
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 300px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1uL62rs/2/)**

Comment: How it is different from the already posted answer by WisdmLabs?

Comment: @Mr_Green there is not required `translate3d` . Check my fiddle

Comment: I thought the same but later realized it must be preferred always for performance. check my comment on that post.

Comment: @Mr_Green it is working inn IE11 also. Check my fiddle in IE11

Comment: Sorry IE10. but it happens sometimes with mix of other css properties. But still your answer is similar to already posted one. You should upvote that instead. and I am not the downvoter.

Comment: @Mr_Green I don't think that my answer answer is similar to that one. I used totally different property than that one. And working on all latest browser.

Comment: Anyway, I hope you got why I am telling to prefer translate3d.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS to your 'childCont' class:

```
.childCont {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%, 0);
}
```

Comment: I don't think `3D` is necessary here.

Comment: It will take the div to the perfect center.

Comment: why is  `top:50%`?

Comment: @WisdmLabs I understand, I was actually trying to say to use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` instead of `transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%, 0)` but realized calling a 3d property must be preferred always. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22111256/1577396)

Comment: @madalin div is pos fixed and need to move  to the center thats why left and top should be 50%

Comment: and also I prefer using `bottom` and `right` properties instead of `top` and `left` because of bug in IE10(_annoying vertical scroll, with some other css properties_) and no need to mention negative operand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use top:50% and right: 50%

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).